# Not able to use .save() while updating (put request) to a mongoose model (with strict set to false)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redux

So I am building yet another CRUD app using the MERN stack (let's use foo as the example). Problem is that in this project I am trying to support an unstructured data stream, so I am setting the Schema to strict:false in the Data Model. All my requests work (get, delete, & post) but when I started working on editing the properties of a foo and sending it to Mongo I get this error.

```
TypeError: foo.save is not a function
```

Here's what my Routes look like for my API

```
 router.route('/foos/:foo_id')

.put(function(req, res){

  foo.findById(req.params.foo_id, function(err, foo) {

    if (err)
      res.send(err);

    foo = req.body;

    foo.save(function(err) {
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json({message: 'foo Updated'});
    });
  })
});
```

Here's what my data model looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var FooSchema = new Schema({
    bar: String,
    foobar: String,
}, { strict: false })

module.exports = mongoose.model('foo', FooSchema);
```

Here's my reducer:

```
case 'SAVE_FOO':
var id = action.foo._id;
var fooEdits = action.foo;

//serialize data to send to Mongo 
function serialize(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}

fetch('http://localhost:7770/api/foos/' + id, {
    method: 'put',
    headers: {  
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  
    },  
    body: serialize(fooEdits) 
})

return state;
```

I am guess this is because i am overwriting the original schema i set for that foo. It works if I pass values defined in my schema, so if I change foo = req.body to foo.bar = req.body.bar it works.

The thing is I want to be able to pass whatever properties into this model and save to mongo, without defining it in the Schema. Is this possible or am I creating the most vulnerable CRUD app known to mankind?

I was thinking I could update my schema to have a customObj:{} then pass all custom properties in there. Then i could do foo.customObj = req.body.customObj, but that seems wrong...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so please let me know how I could better phrase my question or examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo = req.body;
```

change to

```
Object.assign(foo,req.body);
```

Comment: Pretty new to ES6, what's the difference between the two? When i console.log() both of those I get the same result.

Comment: "foo" is an object with prototype of mongoose library,req.body is only a JsonObject